# Not receiving ActionMailer, no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently attempting to send an email by using the following mailer:

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME']

  def contact_email(params)
    @email = params['email']

    mail(to: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'], from: @email, subject: "Contact email from #{@email}")
  end
end
```

I then attempt to send this email using the following controller:

```
class MailerController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    ContactMailer.contact_email(email_params).deliver_now

    render json: { message: 'Email was sent!', email: params['email'] }, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def email_params
    params.permit(
      :name,
      :email,
      :phone,
      :services,
      :message
    )
  end
end
```

When I post to this route, ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] is present and valid, my `email_params` will be filled in, and I will receive a layout for the email.

However, when I check the receiving email account, I have no new emails.

Here is the configuration for the mailer in `./config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# action mailer
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in .`/config/environments/development.rb` and do a test to see if there are errors or not

Comment: @Boris found the issue was with the request and not the actual ActionMailer using delivery errors, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error was not with `ActionMailer`, but rather with my requests, as I provided an empty email in the request body. Rails would throw an error and I only saw it when I added `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to config.